# Numpy : load csv file and read string value using genfromtxt gives warning

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, data-science

I know Warnings are not important, the question might be duplicate but I didn't find a proper solution yet.
I am using the below code for reading the .csv file from the URL.

```
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Auto.csv'
data=np.genfromtxt(path,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,dtype=None)
new_arr=data[:3]
print(new_arr)
```

I want to read numbers and String from the file, I am getting the output

```
[(18., 8, 307., 130, 3504, 12. , 70, 1, b'"chevrolet chevelle malibu"')
 (15., 8, 350., 165, 3693, 11.5, 70, 1, b'"buick skylark 320"')
 (18., 8, 318., 150, 3436, 11. , 70, 1, b'"plymouth satellite"')]
```

But here when I specify dtype=None with output I am also getting the below warning. What is the reason behind this warning?

> ......./Tutorial/PythonProjects/MyTutorials/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2:
>   VisibleDeprecationWarning: Reading unicode strings without specifying
>   the encoding argument is deprecated. Set the encoding, use None for
>   the system default.

As I am new to python and numpy post your comments below.

Comment: Add `encoding=None` to your call.

Comment: it's for only the newer version? New in version 1.14.0. I refered the  link https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Yes, it is relatively new.  I haven't tried to follow the details.  If during testing I get the warning, I just add the `None`, and move on.  There may a patch or issue on `github` that discusses this change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/Auto.csv'
data=np.genfromtxt(path,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,encoding = None)
new_arr=data[:3]
print(new_arr)
```

Not sure about this....but this worked for me.

Comment: data=np.genfromtxt(path,delimiter=',',skip_header=1,dtype=None,encoding = None) the above code with encoding=None it works for me. I looking for the reason for the problem.